# Examples for speech recognition systems and spoken dialogue systems

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, speech-recognition

I am collecting material for a MOOC about speech technology. My aim is that students also have examples to try rather than just watching the lecture and some complimentary youtube videos. So the idea was that they could call up some spoken dialogue systems or something like that. I have quite a few phone numbers of spoken dialogue systems in german (e.g. +498003504030) but as the course is going to be taught in english I am searching for examples in the english language.

Note:

- Examples that will just redirect you to a customer service representative are not of interest.
- I am looking for good and bad examples. If you are aware of phone numbers for some spoken dialogue systems that you like or hate let me know
- If you know a website that lists some numbers to call even better.

So far I had no luck with google and  i hope i have choose the right community on stack overflow for this. If not please accept my apologies in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure this is the right community.

Comment: We seek questions that have answers -- not that call for everyone to contribute an item.  We don't have a strict policy for list questions, but there is a 
[general dislike](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). 
Please note also [this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/20) and
[this](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/145/) discussion; 
you might want to improve your question as to avoid the problems 
explained there.